# Fix tableHeaderView while scrolling UITableViewController with multiple section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header

Is it possible that the tableHeaderView stays on the top even if the tableView has **multiple sections**?

What I have:

A navigationController who leads to a tableViewController 
The header of the tableView is a searchbar (I want it to stay at the top)
and multiple section.
I use swift.

The titles of the sections always stay at the top (replacing each other while scrolling) but I would like that the tableheader always stays at the top and not being replaced by a section title.

1 constraint: I am using a tableViewController and not a View controller (in which I could have a fix uiview and a tableview).

Similarly to what we have when we look in our iPhone contact list

Comment: Is there any reason for using a header view? Otherwise you could just place the search bar in a separate view and position the tableview below the view holding the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my question, the easy way is to add the search in the navigation bar.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    ...
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: yourResultController) // Search Controller
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

This replicate the behavior of the Contact list.

Some other intersting read on how to customize it: http://iosrevisited.blogspot.be/2017/11/add-search-controller-in-navigation-bar-swift.html